# What does rangeError: Invalid status code: 0 mean?

Tags: javascript, express

I am getting my head around express and have this get method:

```
app.get('/myendpoint', function(req, res) {
    var js= JSON.parse ({code: 'success', message:'Valid'});
    res.status(200).json(js);
});
```

When this endpoint is hit I get an error:

```
_http_server.js:192
    throw new RangeError(`Invalid status code: ${statusCode}`);
```

When I comment out the JSON.parse statement and replace the js for some valid json it has no issues? How can I fix this?

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org) != "a JavaScript object" and is *not* created by using JavaScript Object Literal Syntax! Try passing in *actual* JSON, which is *text*. (If starting with a JavaScript object and converting it *to* JSON, such as when sending a reply, there is no need for `JSON.parse` at all.)

Answer (score 1):

No need to `JSON.parse()` in this situation. The function call done incorrectly, since the function expects a string, not an object.

This should work just fine:

```
app.get('/myendpoint', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).json({code: 'success', message:'Valid'});
});
```

[More info in the Express docs.](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json)

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't seem related to the error he's getting.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
res.status(200).send(js);
```

Works.